# How to remove substring from all strings in a list in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings like

```
"00000101000000110110000010010011",
"11110001000000001000000010010011",
```

I need to remove the first 4 characters from each string

so the resulting list will be like

```
"0101000000110110000010010011",
"0001000000001000000010010011",
```

Is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
strings = strings.Select(s => s.Substring(4)).ToList();
```

That will throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception if the string is not at least four characters long, so you may want to do something like

```
strings = strings.Where(s => s.Length >= 4).Select(s => s.Substring(4)).ToList();
```

to remove strings that are too short.

Answer (score 1):

With linq only :

```
l.Select(s => new string(s.Skip(4).ToArray())).ToList();
```

or using Substring

```
l.Select(s => s.Substring(4)).ToList();
```

But with the limitations that Quartermeister noted (Exception if the strings are too small)